# Jest mongo concurrency error

Tags: mongodb, jestjs

**Update** This may be a bug in Jest - watching this issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5731).

I am running Jest tests with Mongo as instructed in the Jest [docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mongodb.html)

When I run more than one test file at the time I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConnectionString' of undefined

      3 | class MongoEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
      4 |   async setup () {
    > 5 |     this.global.__MONGO_URI__ = await global.__MONGOD__.getConnectionString()
      6 |     this.global.__MONGO_DB_NAME__ = global.__MONGO_DB_NAME__
      7 |
      8 |     await super.setup()

      at MongoEnvironment.setup (test/mongo-environment.js:5:57)
```

The only way I can run without error is with the `--runInBand` or `--maxWorkers 1` option.

It doesn't matter what my tests are - I can do dummt tests in each file like:

```
test('Yo', () => {

})
```

So let's say I add this content to `foo.spec.js` and `bar.spec.js` in `test/` dir and do `jest test/` it will yield error.

My jest config:

```
module.exports = {
  globalSetup: './test/setup.js',
  globalTeardown: './test/teardown.js',
  testEnvironment: './test/mongo-environment.js',
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: './test/bootstrap.js',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/config/']
}
```

The setup, teardown and mongo-environment are the same as in Jest docs. My bootstrap file is the before/after hooks:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')

let db

beforeAll(async () => {
  connection = await MongoClient.connect(global.__MONGO_URI__)
  db = await connection.db(global.__MONGO_DB_NAME__)
})

afterAll(async () => {
  await connection.close()
  await db.close()
})
```

Any idea what is going on?

Here are the other files for completness in case I made a booboo:

```
//setup.js
const MongodbMemoryServer = require('mongodb-memory-server')
const MONGO_DB_NAME = 'jest'
const mongod = new MongodbMemoryServer.default({ // eslint-disable-line new-cap
  instance: {
    dbName: MONGO_DB_NAME
  },
  binary: {
    version: '3.2.19'
  }
})

module.exports = function () {
  global.__MONGOD__ = mongod
  global.__MONGO_DB_NAME__ = MONGO_DB_NAME
}


// teardown.js
module.exports = async function () {
  await global.__MONGOD__.stop()
}


//mongo-environment.js
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node')

class MongoEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  async setup () {
    this.global.__MONGO_URI__ = await global.__MONGOD__.getConnectionString()
    this.global.__MONGO_DB_NAME__ = global.__MONGO_DB_NAME__

    await super.setup()
  }

  async teardown () {
    await super.teardown()
  }

  runScript (script) {
    return super.runScript(script)
  }
}

module.exports = MongoEnvironment
```

Note that the error is not 100% consistent - perhaps some kind of timing issue.

This is not just a Mongo thing. If I dump globals in my `MongoEnvironment setup()` method I can see that when running more than one test a whole bunch of Jest globals are missing.

Comment: any update here?